# What do you call a situation when you can't find the things you are currently looking for but finding it when you're not looking for it?

Tags: word-usage

What will be the best word or term to use in that kind of situation?
For example, I am currently looking for my Nursing book inside my house but after days of searching, still no success and I already gave up. However, few weeks or months later I accidentally saw it under my bed when I am cleaning up my room.

I am thinking of the word *"Coincidence"* but I am looking for a more precise word. Luck? hmmm. Not quite sure.

Comment: I would call it "typical."

Answer (score 2):

If you're saying it took you too long to find the book, try

> **[Hofstadter's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter%27s_law):** It always takes longer than you expect, even when you take into account Hofstadter's Law.

---

If you just want to point out that the universe works in weird ways, you can say

> **[Finagle's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finagle's_law):** The perversity of the universe always tends toward a maximum.

Comment: Call it, **LIFE - it's what happens while you're making other plans!** ;- )

Comment: @LittleEva: Lennon's Law, right? :)

Answer (score 2):

When it's vexing, frustrating, I blame mean old "Murphy's Law." When it's unexpected good fortune, it's sweet sister "Serendipity."

Comment: “Sod’s Law” where I come from.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a simple 'Paradox of Life' ,maybe? :) or a sweet fortuitous event